# PHP iterating over an XML

Tags: php, xml, xpath

How can I convert XML to an array that I can iterate over.

Here is the example of my XML

```
<user>
    <student>yes</student>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>John</name>
</user>

<user>
    <student>yes</student>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>Billy</name>
</user>
```

My php looks like this

```
$tmpTemplates = new XDomDocument();
$tmpTemplates->load('.....myFile.xml');
$xPath = new DomXPath($tmpTemplates);
$query = "//user[student='yes']";
$tmpTemplate = $xPath->query($query);
```

What I want to be able to do is

```
foreach($tmpTemplate as $tt){
    var_dump($tt->student);
    var_dump($tt->id);
    var_dump($tt->name);
}
```

Now I'm only able to print out nodeValue which gives me something like this:

> yes
>
> 1
>
> John

How can I make it an array or an object so I can apprach each value by its key?

Comment: Have you tried this [The DOMDocument class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

Answer (score 1):

You used the same id for both records in your example, so I changed the id of the first one and added a document element.

```
<users>
  <user>
    <student>yes</student>
    <id>2</id>
    <name>John</name>
  </user>
  <user>
    <student>yes</student>
    <id>1</id>
     <name>Billy</name>
  </user>
</users>
```

Use `DOMXpath:evaluate()` to fetch the details, the second argument is the context node for the expression.

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml($xmlString);
$xPath = new DomXPath($document);

$students = [];
foreach ($xPath->evaluate("//user[student='yes']") as $student) {
  $id = $xPath->evaluate('string(id)', $student);
  $students[$id] = [
    'id' => $id,
    'name' => $xPath->evaluate('string(name)', $student)
  ];
}

var_dump($students);
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["name"]=>
    string(4) "John"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "Billy"
  }
}
```

The return value depends on the expression. A location path like `//user[student='yes']` or `name` returns a `DOMNodeList`. But you can cast the node list directly in Xpath. `string(name)` will return the contents of the first `name` child node or an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I make it an array or an object so I can apprach each value by its key?

Just for clarification, you've got an object so far, it's the [**SimpleXMLElement**](http://php.net/class.simplexmlelement) and you're using then `$tt` variable to access it:

```
...
    var_dump($tt->student);
    var_dump($tt->id);
    var_dump($tt->name);
...
```

Now that `$tt` variable comes from another variable, namely by iterating over it, and the other variable is named `$tmpTemplate`:

```
...
foreach ($tmpTemplate as $tt) {
    var_dump($tt->student);
    ...
```

That variable by the way is an array. So you can use it by using the index (starting at zero) to access each `<user>` element containing a `<student>` child-element with the value "`student`" in *document-order* (as you formulated the xpath for it):

- `$tmpTemplate[0]` contains the *first* user **SimpleXMLElement**.
- `$tmpTemplate[1]` contains the *second* user **SimpleXMLElement**.
- ... and so on and so forth.

I hope this makes this a bit more visible.

Answer (score 0):

Try with [this php functio](http://php.net/manual/en/function.xml-parse-into-struct.php)n

```
 xml_parse_into_struct
```

sample from php manual

> ```
> <?php
>   $simple = "<para><note>simple note</note></para>";
>   $p = xml_parser_create();
>   xml_parse_into_struct($p, $simple, $vals, $index);
>   xml_parser_free($p);
>   echo "Index array\n";
>   print_r($index);
>   echo "\nVals array\n";
>   print_r($vals);
> ?>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [simplexml_load_file](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.simplexml-load-file.php), which convert xml to object.

For instance :

```
$users = simplexml_load_file("users.xml");
foreach($users as $user) {
   ...
}
```